# Duplicate values from an junction table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, many-to-many, clone

So have have three tables.

`Users(uid,username,email);`

`Studies(sid, studyname);`

`Users_Studies(uid,sid);`

Now lets say the many-many junction table is populated like:
`User_studies(uid,sid)
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,5)
(3,1)
(2,1)`

I create an user that gets uid=4.
And i want that user to get the same connections as uid=1
meaning it should look like this:
`User_studies(uid,sid)
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,5)
(3,1)
(2,1)
(4,1)
(4,2)
(4,5)`

Whats the best way of handling this? looked into stored procedures and while loop without quite figuring it out :) Is there a simple duplicate command? or could someone please guide me in the best way to do this :)

Comment: hmm still having some issues with it. Im trying to get the uid based of the username and not the id value :P

Comment: Figured it out
`insert into User_studies(uid,sid) 
select user.uid,user_studies.sid
from Users,Users_studies
Where User.uid = 4
AND User_studies. = 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
INSERT INTO User_studies (uid, sid)
SELECT 4, sid
FROM   User_studies
WHERE  uid = 1
```

Comment: >< i've sat for hours scratching my head doing all kind of crazy stuff and it was as simple as that :P THANKS! :)

Comment: I will change 4 with an variable from the stored procedure call. The command itself worked (just tried)

Comment: @roadrunner66 "Select 4" always returns 4 in that position. Useful when you have a known value, like a new uid, to put into a join table. It's the best way to duplicate existing data but for a new PK.

Comment: found this approach best. insert into User_studies(uid,sid) select user.uid,user_studies.sid from Users,Users_studies Where User.uid = 4 AND User_studies. = 1; number 4,1 is now variables passed through the stored procedure call

Comment: @Karelzarath. Thank you. Didnt' know that was your intent. Learnt something : )

Comment: @svennand That works until you have a large number of users. Then, the extra join to pull in one row will start to drag down your query's performance.

Comment: @Karelzarath Hmm. How would you resolve that? would it be better to pull  both out to the local user web session and handling it there instead and then send iterated content back? That beeing said, this function is only to be used from the administrator side and not by average user. So it wont be something that constantly gets throughputted :) But allways good to learn best practice from the getgo :)